# Is $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : xy=0 \}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Is $\{(x,0) : x \in \mathbb R \} \cup \{(0,y) : y \in \mathbb R \}$ homeomorphic to  $\mathbb R$ ? I am totally stuck and I don't even have any intuition whether they should be homeomorphic or not . Please help . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: How many components does the set have if you remove the origin? Can this happen when you remove a point of $\Bbb R$?

**Added:** Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic spaces, with $h:X\to Y$ a homeomorphism. Suppose further that $C$ is a connected component of $X$. Then $h[C]$ is a connected component of $Y$. Clearly $h[C]$ is connected, since it’s the continuous image of a connected set. Suppose that $h[C]\subsetneqq D$, where $D$ is connected; then $h^{-1}[D]$ would be a connected subset of $X$ properly containing $C$, which is impossible. Thus, $h[C]$ is a component of $Y$. This shows that $h$ sends components to components. If $\mathscr{C}_X$ and $\mathscr{C}_Y$ are the sets of components of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, and $H:\mathscr{C}_X\to\mathscr{C}_Y:C\mapsto h[C]$, then $H$ is a bijection.,

Comment: You mean connected components ? If we delete  the origin from the union of two axes then there are four connected components and in case of $\mathbb R$ , removal of any point gives two components . But how to turn this into a rigorous proof ?

Comment: @Saun: Ben Millwood’s answer contains the answer that I was just about to give to your question here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott is it true that if two spaces $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic then no. of connected components are same in both?

Comment: @learnmore: Yes, it is. Continuous functions preserve connectedness.

Comment: yes that's true I know but how to use this to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic then there exits  a bijective mapping from the set of connected components of $A$ to $B$?

Comment: Do you mind asking questions here or I should ask a fresh question? Please let me know

Comment: Excellent and thank you very much

Comment: @learnmore: You’re very welcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22766/discussion-between-learnmore-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: @learnmore: Okay, I’m there.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I can't help but feel it's a bit awkward to have steps 1 and 3 in your answer and step 2 in mine :) do you want to edit anything you think my answer contributes into this one, and then I'll delete mine? (I care about tidiness more than reputation :P )

Comment: @Ben: If you want to delete yours, I think that mine can still stand as is, especially with the existing comments.